# FFmpeg - Generating waveform image from webm file not working due to overlay filter

Tags: ffmpeg, waveform, webm

I am attempting to generate a waveform image from a webm file. I am using the overlay filter to overlay the waveform atop a background. The waveform does not show whenever the overlay filter is used. The failing command:

```
ffmpeg -i big_buck_bunny.webm -filter_complex "showwavespic=s=640x120[fg];color=s=640x120:color=#ff0000[bg];[bg][fg]overlay=format=auto" -frames:v 1 output.jpg
```

The result:

[image]

I have also tried using an image as the background with the same result:

```
ffmpeg -i big_buck_bunny.webm -i bg.jpg -filter_complex "showwavespic=s=640x120[fg];[1:v][fg]overlay=format=auto" -frames:v 1 output.jpg
```

Generating a waveform without a background works as expected:

```
ffmpeg -i big_buck_bunny.webm -filter_complex "showwavespic=s=640x120" -frames:v 1 output.jpg
```

[image]

[Here](http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm) is the video I am using.

I have tried various webm files with the same result. I also tested some .mp4,.mov,.ogv files which worked as expected. I am using the latest ffmpeg version, below is my banner.

```
ffmpeg version 4.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.0.1 --enable-shared -- 
enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma
libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As my test result, the output of `showwavespic` filter has a non-zero pts (presentation timestamp) when the input is webm format. So the `overlay` filter doesn't work for the 1st frame. If you output 2 frames (and change the background color) like this:

```
ffmpeg -i big_buck_bunny.webm -filter_complex "showwavespic=s=640x120[fg];color=s=640x120:color=#ffff00[bg];[bg][fg]overlay=format=auto" -frames:v 2 output%d.jpg
```

You'll see the 2nd frame is what you want. And you can print the pts by adding the `showinfo` filter:

```
ffmpeg -i big_buck_bunny.webm -filter_complex "showwavespic=s=640x120,showinfo[fg];color=s=640x120:color=#ffff00[bg];[bg][fg]overlay=format=auto,showinfo" -frames:v 2 output%d.jpg
```

I don't know why it happens. But you can fix this problem by simply force the pts of `showwavespic` filter to be 0:

```
ffmpeg -i big_buck_bunny.webm -filter_complex "showwavespic=s=640x120,setpts=0[fg];color=s=640x120:color=#ffff00[bg];[bg][fg]overlay=format=auto" -frames:v 1 output.jpg
```